# Question concerning seemingly similar but somehow different Python Syntax

Tags: python, syntax, absolute-value

I thought this should work, but it didn't (yields 0):

```
n1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

pair = zip(n1, n2)

dif = sum(abs(v1 - v2) for v1, v2 in pair)
print(dif)
```

But neglecting my pair variable and using the code directly worked just fine (yields 16):

```
dif = sum(abs(v1 - v2) for v1, v2 in zip(n1, n2))
```

Shouldn't both of them yield the same answer?

Comment: I get 16 for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach is supposed to work. If I was to guess why it's not, maybe you've already iterated over the 'pair' variable before you used it in your generator expression

Comment: Yea, I thought the same, probably the generator has already been used before the expression

Comment: You are right guys, thank you for helping me out. I am simply stupid... I used a print statement `print(*pair)`  in order to check the structure. I did not know that this could have implications.

Thanks again! :) @Seth250, @dome